# how do you take in the enter key as an input?

Tags: c++, input, char

I have been trying to take the enter key in as an input for my program. I have defined a char ENTER variable and used cin >> ENTER; to take in the enter key. Then I have used an if statement to determine whether the Enter key was press. if(ENTER == '13'), '13' is the ascii code for enter. It doesn't seem to be working, any suggestions?

Comment: Post your code and tell us exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1893/

Answer (score 1):

How to detect the Enter Key without corrupting valid input:

```
char c;
cin.get(c);               // get a single character
if (c == 10) return 0;    // 10 = ascii linefeed (Enter Key) so exit
else cin.putback(c);      // put the character back and proceed normally
```

Alternatively:

```
char c;
c = cin.peek();           // read next character without extracting it
if (c == '\n') return 0;  // linefeed (Enter Key) so exit
```

Comment: You should change `c` to type int  and compare it to the literal `\n` to avoid confusion